# How to write sql query for adding days given by the user to the current date where current date and days to be added need to be taken as parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE @currDate DATETIME
DECLARE @days INT
SELECT DATEADD(dd ,@days ,@currDate)
WHERE  @days             = 10
AND @currDate     = GETDATE()
```

Comment: Please add tag for the specific DB type you're using (my guess is SQL Server, but not sure), and what specific problem you are facing - what's wrong with the code you've posted?

Comment: m not getting any output for dis query...its showing blank

Comment: n also i don't want the number of days added to be hardcoded...

Comment: nd its sql server 2008R2

Answer (score 0):

Assuming SQLServer, this will add 1 day to current date. You can apply further functions to extract only date part etc.

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, current_timestamp);
```

Replace current_timestamp with any other date you want.

[SQLFiddle example here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fb808/9)

Answer (score 0):

It is so simple as below,

```
DECLARE @days AS INT=10
DECLARE @currDate AS DATE=GETDATE()
SELECT DATEADD(DAY ,@days ,@currDate) AS AddedDate
```